# Unreadable text in WinForm DateTimePicker control on Terminal Server

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

Today I stumbled about a strange problem with the standard `WinForms DateTimePicker` control. For users starting my application on a terminal server session the `DateTimePicker` looks like the following image:

[image: This is the Image of my problem]

I can't find any solution to this problem. I tried setting the Font property of the DateTimePicker without success. When I start the application on my local PC everything looks fine.

Any suggestions?! Does anybody has similar problems?

Comment: Reinstall the application or `.net redistributable`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this earlier. I already tried reinstalling the application. Reinstalling .net is a little bit tricky because the server is in a productive environment and I can't stop 30 workmates from working right now but the .net installation seems to be valid and all other programs work well.

Comment: Then develop another application and use `datetimepicker` and see the results. If the problem is same, then some thing is wrong with your .net

Comment: this is the first time I've seen such a strange thing with any standard control,

Comment: I tried what you suggested and created a simple WinForm application with a few DateTimePicker on it. Everythings is displayed correctly. So it seems not to be a .net installation problem.